# Linux - Find all occurrences of a certain pattern in a line of a file

Tags: shell-script, pattern-matching

I have a file in Linux which contains a line like :

```
(memberOf=CN=Group1)(memberOf=CN=Group2)(memberOf=CN=Group3)(memberOf=CN=Group4)
```

My goal is to populate the list of groups that is present in the line, like -

```
Group1

Group2

Group3

Group4
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. On one hand the title says you want to match a pattern in a file, but on the other you say you want to populate names of groups, not match them.  Could you please clarify the issue and give more explicit examples?

Answer (score 3):

With `pcregrep` (`P`erl `C`ompatible `R`egular `E`xpression `grep`):

```
pcregrep -io1 '\(memberOf=CN=(.*?)\)'
```

Or directly with `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 while /\(memberOf=CN=(.*?)\)/gi'
```

(here using `-i` or the `i` flag as LDAP attributes names are case insensitive).

If your `grep` implementation supports the `-P` option (like GNU `grep` does when built with PCRE support), then it most likely also supports the non-standard `-o` option and you could do:

```
grep -iPo '\(memberOf=CN=\K.*?(?=\))'
```

Here using `\K` and a look-ahead operator for the `(memberOf=CN=` and `)` not to be included in the output since `grep` implementations other than `pcregrep` don't support outputting capture groups.

With POSIX utilities, you can do something roughly equivalent  with:

```
sed -n '
  /([mM][eE][mM][bB][eE][rR][Oo][fF]=[Cc][Nn]=\([^)]*\))\(.*\)/ {
    s//\
\1\
\2/
    s/.*\n\(.*\n\)/\1/
    P;D
  }'
```

If that string is stored in a shell scalar variable, and you want the resulting groups to be stored in a shell array variable, with the `zsh` shell, you could do:

```
set -o extendedglob

string='(memberOf=CN=Group1)(memberOf=CN=Group2)(memberOf=CN=Group3)(memberOf=CN=Group4)'
groups=()

: ${string//(#ib)[(]memberOf=CN=([^)]#)[)]/${groups[$#groups+1]=$match[1]}}
```

Or get it from GNU `grep` with:

```
groups=(
  ${(0)"$(
    print -rN -- $string |
      grep -ziPo '\(memberOf=CN=\K.*?(?=\))'
  )"}
)
```

Same with bash 4.4+:

```
readarray -td '' groups < <(
  printf '%s\0' "$string" |
    grep -ziPo '\(memberOf=CN=\K.*?(?=\))'
) && wait "$!"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne 'put $/.join("\n") if m:g/\(memberOf\=CN\= <(.*?)> \)/;'
```

OR

```
raku -ne 'put $/.join("\n") if m:g/<?after \(memberOf\=CN\= > (.*?) <?before \) > /;'
```

Briefly, example 1 uses the `<(…)>` match delimiters in Raku which instructs the regex engine to drop everything in the match outside of `<(.*?)>`. Example 2 uses a `<?after "pattern1" >` positive lookbehind and a `<?before "pattern2" >` positive lookahead to isolate everything in-between. If case-insensitivity is important, then simply change `m:g` ('match-global') to `m:g:i` ('match-global case-insensitive').

Sample Input:

```
(memberOf=CN=Group1)(memberOf=CN=Group2)(memberOf=CN=Group3)(memberOf=CN=Group4)
```

Sample Output (1):

```
Group1
Group2
Group3
Group4
```

OR Sample Output (2):

```
Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4
```

Imagining for a second that the OP has a file with multiple, similar lines to the example line shown, then it may make sense to return output all on one line. For either of the above examples, simply changing `$/.join("\n")` to `$/` causes each linewise capture to return linewise (Output 2, above).

Finally, the OP may have positional information encoded within the 'Group' listing (e.g. lower group #s on the left, higher on the right). In that case it may make more sense to `comb()`-out the matches and display them as `.pairs`, as below:

```
raku -ne '.raku.say for .comb(/<?after \(memberOf\=CN\= > (.*?) <?before \) > /).pairs;' 

0 => "Group1"
1 => "Group2"
2 => "Group3"
3 => "Group4"
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to go about this, here’s a solution using widely available features of `grep` with an emphasis on easier human readability.

As you haven’t stated how the input is arriving, I’ve assumed pipeline. It would be trivial to adapt to file input.

```
echo "(memberOf=CN=Group1)(memberOf=CN=Group2)(memberOf=CN=Group3)(memberOf=CN=Group4)" \
  | grep -Eo "[(]memberOf=CN=[^)]+" \
  | grep -Eo "[^=]+$"
```

This works in two phases.

Firstly we extract all `(memberOf=CN=something` patterns without the closing `)` — this is important for our second phase.  These come out one to a line “for free” which makes our job easier in step two.  Any strings in the input that do not conform to this pattern will be disregarded, so it should also work where the required strings are buried in amongst other things.

Next we match everything that isn’t `=`, starting at the end of the line and working backwards. This has the effect of dropping the `memberOf=CN=` part of the string.

If the case of the input cannot be guaranteed, add `i` to the flags on the first `grep`.

One caveat: if there are escaped `)` or `=` in your `CN` values this will not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is somewhat similar to `@bxm`'s, but with a `sed` step instead of purely `grep`.

```
grep -Eo '\(memberOf=CN=[^()]*\)' |
sed 's/(memberOf=CN=\(.*\))/\1/'
```

Input:

```
(memberOf=CN=Group1)(memberOf=CN=Group2)(memberOf=CN=Group3)(memberOf=CN=Group4)
(memberOf=CN=GroupA1)
(memberOf=CN=GroupA2)(memberOf=CN=GroupA3)
(memberOf=CN=GroupA4)
(rememberOf=CN=GroupX1)(memberOf=CN=GroupX2)
(numberOf=CN=GroupX4)
(memberOf=CN=GroupB1)(memberOf=CN=GroupB2)(memberOf=CN=GroupB3)(memberOf=CN=GroupB4)
```

Output:

```
Group1
Group2
Group3
Group4
GroupA1
GroupA2
GroupA3
GroupA4
GroupX2
GroupB1
GroupB2
GroupB3
GroupB4
```

The output from `grep` appears on `sed`'s input as:

```
(memberOf=CN=Group1)
(memberOf=CN=Group2)
(memberOf=CN=Group3)
(memberOf=CN=Group4)
...
```

`sed` then takes that output and strips off the leading `(memberOf=CN=` and the trailing `)`.

This code could be made slightly more general by wildcarding more of the `sed` line:

```
grep -Eo '\(memberOf=CN=[^()]*\)' |
sed 's/.*=\(.*\))/\1/'
```